# Update stored procedure - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have an error and I cannot find the reason for failing of this procedure. All I know it does something I have no clue about. Does anyone have an idea what is this about? :|

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateAccountPersonJob] 
    @department nvarchar(50),
    @description nvarchar(50),
    @personID int,
    @name nvarchar(50),
    @surname nvarchar(50),
    @email nvarchar(50),
    @username nvarchar(50),
    @password nvarchar(50),
    @status nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    DECLARE @missionID int, @jobID int;
    BEGIN TRY

       SET @jobID = (SELECT id FROM Jobs 
                     WHERE department = @department AND description = @description)

       UPDATE Persons 
       SET name = @name, surname = @surname, email = @email, jobID = @jobID 
       WHERE Persons.id = @personID

       UPDATE Accounts 
       SET Username = @username, Password = @password, Status = @status  
       WHERE Accounts.Password = @personID
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
            ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
            ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
            ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
            ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
            ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

        BEGIN IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            PRINT('ROLLBACK')
        END
    END CATCH;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

EXEC:

```
EXEC [dbo].updateAccountPersonJob
        @department = N'Facultatea de Matematica si Informatica',
        @description = N'Teacher',
        @personID = N'16',
        @name = N'Dummy',
        @surname = N'BarFOO',
        @email = N'bar@ba.com',
        @username = N'dummy',
        @password = N'd',
        @status = N'Teacher'
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'director' to data type int.

Comment: If you run the `SELECT id FROM Jobs WHERE department = @department AND description = @description` what do you get as a result?

Comment: can you edit your question with the table structures for both tables?  Do you have any triggers on the tables?

Comment: @BogdanM., this might not be related to error you are getting, you are checking personid against password column

Comment: omg.. .. .. .. thank you, please post it as respons, I'm against clock, and it seems i'm pretty tired...

Comment: Also the error message implies that you are storing the passwords in plain text. This is bad. At the very least you should be hashing/salting them and comparing the hashes.

Comment: thank you, but I'm a student, and it is all about a project we need to do toughter, not really into to cryptic / hashing stuff :p, ty altought for the toughtful opservation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are checking `personid` (integer) column against `password` column which is nvarchar. Update you query to use correct parameter or column and your code should work